# Testing time critical code

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, time

I've written a feature for my library [Rubikon](http://koraktor.github.com/rubikon) that displays a throbber (a spinning — as you may have seen in other console apps) as long as some other code is running.

To test this feature I capture the output of the throbber in a `StringIO` and compare it with the expected value. As the throbber is only displayed as long as the other code is running the content of the `IO` gets longer when the code runs longer. In my tests I do a simple `sleep 1` and should have a constant 1 second delay. This works most of the time, but sometimes (apparently due to external factors like heavy load on the CPU) it fails, because the code doesn't run for 1 second, but for a bit more, so that the throbber prints a few additional characters.

My question is: Is there any possibility to test such time critical features in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your github repository, I found this test for the Throbber class:

```
should 'work correctly' do
  ostream = StringIO.new
  thread = Thread.new { sleep 1 }
  throbber = Throbber.new(ostream, thread)
  thread.join
  throbber.join
  assert_equal " \b-\b\\\b|\b/\b", ostream.string
end
```

I'll assume that a throbber iterates over `['-', '\', '|', '/']`, backspacing before each write, once per second.  Consider the following test:

```
should 'work correctly' do
  ostream = StringIO.new
  started_at = Time.now
  ended_at = nil
  thread = Thread.new { sleep 1; ended_at = Time.now }
  throbber = Throbber.new(ostream, thread)
  thread.join
  throbber.join
  duration = ended_at - started_at
  iterated_chars = " -\\|/"
  expected = ""
  if duration >= 1
    # After n seconds we should have n copies of " -\\|/", excluding \b for now
    expected << iterated_chars * duration.to_i
  end
  # Next append the characters we'd get from working for fractions of a second:
  remainder = duration - duration.to_i
  expected << iterated_chars[0..((iterated_chars.length*remainder).to_i)] if remainder > 0.0
  expected = expected.split('').join("\b") + "\b"
  assert_equal expected, ostream.string
end
```

The last assignment of `expected` is a bit unpleasant, but I made the assumption that the throbber would write character/backspace pairs atomically.  If this is not true, you should be able to insert the \b escape sequence into the iterated_chars string and remove the last assignment entirely.

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar (I think, altough I'm not completely sure) to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322593/what-is-a-precise-way-to-block-a-thread-for-a-specific-period-of-time/1322633#1322633):

> Only real time operating system can
>   give you such precision. You can
>   assume Thread.Sleep has a precision of
>   about 20 ms so you could, in theory
>   sleep until the desired time - the
>   actual time is about 20 ms and THEN
>   spin for 20 ms but you'll have to
>   waste those 20 ms. And even that
>   doesn't guarantee that you'll get real
>   time results, the scheduler might just
>   take your thread out just when it was
>   about to execute the RELEVANT part
>   (just after spinning)

The problem is not rubby (possibly, I'm no expert in ruby), the problem is the real time capabilities of your operating system.

Comment: I know that I can't expect real time behaviour from a non-realtime OS and especially from a script language like Ruby. My question is not about eliminating delays to get real time behaviour, I just want to eliminate side effects in unit tests.